# How can I get distcc compilation to work in a distributed way via a systemd service?

Tags: services, init-script

I have two machines, both running Ubuntu 20.04, and I'm trying to compile some C++ code in a distributed way via distcc (version 3.3.3).

When I launch the distcc daemon manually on one machine and compile on the other, everything seems to work.
I use the following command to launch the daemon:

```
distccd --no-detach --daemon --allow 192.168.0.0/16 --allow 127.0.0.1 --nice 10 --jobs 8 --zeroconf
```

I can tell it's working since I'm seeing jobs execute and complete successfully both on the server and localhost in gnome distcc monitor on the machine where I launch the compilation.

Also, when I run `nmap` on either machine (querying the server) with this setup I get this output:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
3632/tcp open  distccd distccd v1 (unknown compiler)
```

When I simply run distcc as a service instead of launching it manually, I get the following outputs:

```
$ sudo service distcc start
$ sudo service distcc status
distcc.service - LSB: simple distributed compiler server
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/distcc; generated)
 Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-12-16 15:16:03 EST; 22s ago
   Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 9183 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/distcc start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Tasks: 10 (limit: 38405)
 Memory: 3.7M
 CGroup: /system.slice/distcc.service
         ├─9193 /usr/bin/distccd --pid-file=/var/run/distccd.pid --log-file=/var/log/distccd.log --daemon --allow 192.168.0.0/16 --allow 127.0.0.1 --listen 127.0.0.1 --nice 10 --jobs 8 --zeroconf
         ├─9199 /usr/bin/distccd --pid-file=/var/run/distccd.pid --log-file=/var/log/distccd.log --daemon --allow 192.168.0.0/16 --allow 127.0.0.1 --listen 127.0.0.1 --nice 10 --jobs 8 --zeroconf
         ├─9200 /usr/bin/distccd --pid-file=/var/run/distccd.pid --log-file=/var/log/distccd.log --daemon --allow 192.168.0.0/16 --allow 127.0.0.1 --listen 127.0.0.1 --nice 10 --jobs 8 --zeroconf
         ├─9201 /usr/bin/distccd --pid-file=/var/run/distccd.pid --log-file=/var/log/distccd.log --daemon --allow 192.168.0.0/16 --allow 127.0.0.1 --listen 127.0.0.1 --nice 10 --jobs 8 --zeroconf
         ├─9202 /usr/bin/distccd --pid-file=/var/run/distccd.pid --log-file=/var/log/distccd.log --daemon --allow 192.168.0.0/16 --allow 127.0.0.1 --listen 127.0.0.1 --nice 10 --jobs 8 --zeroconf
         ├─9209 /usr/bin/distccd --pid-file=/var/run/distccd.pid --log-file=/var/log/distccd.log --daemon --allow 192.168.0.0/16 --allow 127.0.0.1 --listen 127.0.0.1 --nice 10 --jobs 8 --zeroconf
         ├─9210 /usr/bin/distccd --pid-file=/var/run/distccd.pid --log-file=/var/log/distccd.log --daemon --allow 192.168.0.0/16 --allow 127.0.0.1 --listen 127.0.0.1 --nice 10 --jobs 8 --zeroconf
         ├─9211 /usr/bin/distccd --pid-file=/var/run/distccd.pid --log-file=/var/log/distccd.log --daemon --allow 192.168.0.0/16 --allow 127.0.0.1 --listen 127.0.0.1 --nice 10 --jobs 8 --zeroconf
         └─9212 /usr/bin/distccd --pid-file=/var/run/distccd.pid --log-file=/var/log/distccd.log --daemon --allow 192.168.0.0/16 --allow 127.0.0.1 --listen 127.0.0.1 --nice 10 --jobs 8 --zeroconf
```

The launcher line seems to correspond to what I do manually (i.e. seems like I've configured `/etc/default/distcc` correctly). Here are the contents of `/etc/default/distcc`, just in case (sans comments):

```
STARTDISTCC="true"

ALLOWEDNETS="192.168.0.0/16 127.0.0.1"

LISTENER="127.0.0.1"

NICE="10"

JOBS="8"

ZEROCONF="true"
```

However, when I run `nmap` to query port 3632 on the server again, here's what happens:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE VERSION
3632/tcp closed distccd
```

I have set up the host lists on both machines in `~/.distcc/hosts` following the IP/LIMIT notation (using `localhost/8` for the local machine and `other-machines-ip/8` for the other machine).

Do you know how can I get the distcc service to work?

Comment: Are you using distcc installed from the Ubuntu package repository? Have you made any changes to the systemd service configuration?

Comment: @MosheKatz Yes, I am using the default distcc installed from the Ubuntu package repository, and no, I haven't made any changes to systemd service configuration. If you think systemd service configuration may be suspect (idk, artifacts from system upgrade or something), what would you look at to check?

Comment: You need to show distcc file content. Otherwise, how would we know what the service is configured to do?

Comment: @Braiam  Here, I've pasted the file contents. For reference, ALLOWEDNETS setting directly translates to all the entries of `--allow` in the output of `sudo service distcc status` , LISTENER directly translates to what goes behind `--listen`, ZEROCONF influences whether --zeroconf flag is added, values for NICE and JOBS influence the --nice and --jobs respectively. Without STARTDISTCC being set to true the service cannot start at all.

Comment: "LISTENER="127.0.0.1"" <--- here is your problem. You are listening on localhost.

Comment: @Braiam, if you want to go ahead and phrase that as the answer, i. e. that the machine's local IP needs to be there instead, I'll accept your answer. I had two other people with both code and networking experience look at this issue and miss this subtle detail, one asked me to notify him of the result, so this might be valuable.

Comment: Considering that there has not yet been a response by @Braiam, you can post create and accept your answer in order to have this question marked as "solved" for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

The subtle detail I have missed was the additional --listen argument to the daemon in the case of the systemd service as shown in the original post. The --listen argument is controlled by the LISTENER setting in `/etc/default/distcc` and the default is 127.0.0.1, which causes only connections from localhost to be accepted.

I should have set it to `192.168.0.1` in my case to listen to all machines on the local network.